# Singleton и реализация

Tags: c++, singleton

Если я создаю класс в качестве одиночки, то нужно ли реализовать оперетор присваивания, конструктор копирования, операторы сравнения классов и т.д? Как их вообще записать? Просто без объявить, но не писать реализацию?

И заодно спрошу, как реализовать Singleton, если объект класса будет создаваться как

```
Class * c = new Class();
```

а не так

```
Class c;
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Классический (и наиболее изящный) метод объявления синглтона на C++ — синглтон Майерса. Пример:

```
class Singleton
{
  public:
    static Singleton& Instance()
    {
        // согласно стандарту, этот код ленивый и потокобезопасный
        static Singleton s;
        return s;
    }

  private:
    Singleton() { ... }  // конструктор недоступен
    ~Singleton() { ... } // и деструктор

    // необходимо также запретить копирование
    Singleton(Singleton const&); // реализация не нужна
    Singleton& operator= (Singleton const&);  // и тут
};
```

Начиная с C++11, правильнее писать так:

```
Singleton(Singleton const&) = delete;
Singleton& operator= (Singleton const&) = delete;
```

Теперь по пунктам:

1. Оператор присваивания не нужен. Поскольку он во многих случаях создаётся компилятором «за вашей спиной», нужно задекларировать его приватным, чтобы им никто не мог воспользоваться. В C++11 вы можете прямо убрать его при помощи конструкции «`= delete`».
2. То же для конструктора копирования.
3. В операторах сравнения нет нужды, так как всё равно есть лишь один экземпляр. Поскольку автоматически операторы сравнения не создаются, вам не нужно ни о чём беспокоиться.
4. Использовать синглтон, создавая его явно, нельзя: ведь если вы смогли объявить один экземпляр, то сможете объявить сколько угодно! Поэтому варианты «ручного» создания мы исключили, сделав конструктор приватным. Получить ссылку на синглтон для работы с ним можно только так:

   ```
   Singleton& instance = Singleton::Instance();
   ```

Comment: @andrey3: деструктор приватный, чтобы не возникало соблазна написать `delete &Singleton::Instance();`

И кстати, никакого наследования вам не нужно. Зачем вам наследоваться от синглтонного класса, если вы всё равно не имеете права создавать объекты порождённого класса?

И ещё раз: экземпляр синглтона **нельзя** создать при помощи `new` и нельзя уничтожить. Иначе это уже будет не синглтон, а что-то другое.

Comment: @VladD я имею ввиду, если Singleton наследуется от класса не Singleton

Comment: @andrey3: А, так можно, конечно. Но тогда приватный конструктор и деструктор — не помеха, всё равно их нельзя вызывать пользовательскому коду.

Comment: @VladD и относительно С++11. Там const правильно стоит? Почему?

Comment: @andrey3: Согласно [документации](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor), copy constructor может иметь или не иметь `const`. Достаточно отменить любой из copy constructor'ов, чтобы другой не создался.

---
А, вы про это! На самом деле, можно для любого типа писать `const T` и `T const`, смысл не меняется. Поскольку названия типов надо читать справа налево, мне кажется, что `const` справа предпочтительнее. Но это вопрос вкуса.

---
Если коротко — это одно и то же.

Comment: @andrey3: Да. Точно так же, как и конструктор. Приватный — лишь область видимости, компилятор всё равно обеспечивает своевременный вызов конструкторов и деструкторов.

Заметьте, однако, что деструктор вызовется после окончания работы функции `main`.

---
Эээ... А что такое «как обычно»? Когда?

Comment: @VladD "как обычно" это например, если я создаю экземпляр класса в функции, то после окончания ее работы объект удалится. То есть, наверное мне нужно сделать функцию reset. Внутри которой приблизительно следующее: delete &obj_singleton;

Comment: @andrey3: Нет. Объект синглтона НЕ создаётся/уничтожается по желанию. Он ОДИН на весь пробег программы по определению того, что такое синглтон.

Если вам нужно уничтожить объект, не пользуйтесь синглтоном.

Comment: @VladD А что с move constructor?